# In AppleScript, how do I copy a directory's contents to another directory without deleting the destination directory's existing files?

Tags: file, automation, applescript

I'm trying to copy files and directories from one directory called "Motion Templates" to another directory called "Motion Templates".

```
tell application "Finder"
    set srcPath to ((parent of (path to me) as text) & "Motion Templates")
    set dstPath to (((path to movies folder) as text) & "Motion Templates")
    set srcFolder to folder srcPath
    set dstFolder to folder dstPath

    duplicate entire contents of srcFolder to dstFolder with replacing
end tell
```

The source directory (Motion Templates) contains a subdirectory (Generators) which successfully copies over to the destination "Motion Templates" in terms of matching file paths (from a source "Motion Templates/Generators" to a destination "Motion Templates/Generators"). However, this script also deletes all of the existing subdirectories that existed in "Motion Templates/Generators". How do I go about copying/overwriting files without deleting the other existing files in the tree?

Answer (score 0):

This is far to confusing to explain when you are using the same names. It's like trying to understand Who's on first for the first time. Try using different folder names until you can get it working then worry about what things are called.

To try and help the only thing I can say is if the files have the same exact names and you use the "with replacing" it will overwrite what ever is in the destination folder. If you are saying the source folder is being deleted then you are having an issue where the files are being moved and not duplicated.